# java.lang.SecurityException from NotificationManager?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, push-notification, securityexception

We use push notifications in our game to notify users about certain in-game things when the game receives a pause/suspend call from the engine.

I've been looking at crash logs from the Google Developer Console and a large porition of them is caused by a `SecurityException` from the use of push noticiations.

Call stack:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2697)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:178)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1466)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5560)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:844)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1425)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1379)
  at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag (INotificationManager.java:239)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:132)
  at android.app.NotificationManager.notify (NotificationManager.java:108)
  at tinytitan.tinylib.NotificationPublisher.onReceive (NotificationPublisher.java:21)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2690)
```

That 'tinytitan' line is from our Java push notif plugin. Source code:

```
package tinytitan.tinylib;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    /**
     * Called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent
     */
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification); // <-- LINE# 21
    }
}
```

Here's out manifest files (there's multiple cause we use different plugins):

**Why are we getting this exception and how to fix it?**

*EDIT* I tried posting the Manifest files content but the formatting wouldn't let me do it, so I stripped out the angle brackets.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"
uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
```

**EDIT:** Rest of the plugin's code:

```
/**
 * Shows a Notification with a delay
 */
public static void scheduleNotification(int id, long delayMs, String title, String message, boolean vibrate, boolean lightBlink, boolean sound, String largeImage, String smallImage)
{
    Notification notification = getNotification(title, message, vibrate, lightBlink, sound, smallImage, largeImage);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delayMs;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}

/**
 * Cancels a notification waiting to be added to the notification query or removes a notification
 * from the notification query.
 */
public static void cancelNotification(int id)
{
    //Remove it from the alarm manager (if present)
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, NotificationPublisher.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(UnityPlayer.currentActivity, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);

    //remove it from the notification query (if present)
    android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(id);
}

/**
 * Removes all notifications that are in the notification query
 */
public static void clearAll(){
    android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager)UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

The call from C#:

```
    TinyAndroidServices.ScheduleNotification(id, delay, title, message, true, true, true, "app_icon", androidSmallIcon);
```

Comment: please share the permission in your mainfest

Comment: @Hala.M Done. Please check my edit.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I have the same crash reports

Comment: @j2esu No not yet, we just disabled push notifs for now.

Comment: @vexe have you found any solution?

Comment: @ArturLatoszewski I barely remember asking this, been a while lol

Answer (score 0):

You should use this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Not this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have that permission. I've editied to include the permissions I use.

Comment: Show your notification object @vexe

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by 'notification object' I posted the rest of the plugin code. Maybe you mean the result from the getNotification function?

Comment: How is READ_PHONE_STATE related to the crash?